# How to cover a C++ legacy code controlled by preprocessor #ifdefs with unittests?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, c-preprocessor, legacy-code

I have inherited a not too big C++ legacy code which I am currently reengineering. So far I understand most of the code quite well and am able to use it, though the maintenance is hell. I think the main difficulty lies in the MASSIVE use of preprocessor directives to control the behaviour of the program.

Consider the following examples:

```
void function(){
    ... // lots of code 
    #ifdef PARAMETER == 1
        do_one_thing();

    #elif PARAMETER == 2
        do_another_thing();
    ...//etc
    #endif
    ...//lots of code
}
```

or

```
void function(double arg1,
             #ifdef SOME_PP_VAR1 == 5
             double arg2,
             #endif
             )
```

and stuff like

```
#ifdef SOME_PP_VAR2 == 2
    typedef myVector std::vector<double>;
#elif SOME_PP_VAR2 == 7
    typedef myVector std::vector<int>;
#endif
```

in the global scope. Or even

```
#ifdef SOME_PP_VAR2 == 2
    #include "some_header.hpp"
#elif SOME_PP_VAR2 == 7
    #include "some_other_header.hpp"
#endif
```

About 30 of such preprocessor variables are set in a configuration file which is passed to the build system and then to the compiler. It basically controls everything and is present in almost any file. By the way, in some places the #ifs are even nested.

Therefore, it is quite difficult to write unit tests. I would have to build all of the possible combinations of the preprocessor variables and test each.

My (poor) ideas so far are:

- Rewrite the code from scratch, possibly in a different language. (High risk, too time-consuming).
- Replace the preprocessor variables by constants. (Not always feasible).

Did you ever encounter such a situation and how did you handle it?

Comment: This coding method is complete madness and the sooner you can get rid of all those `#ifdef` statements the better. What you may want to do is create custom build scripts to compile it in N different forms, then verify that it's working correctly in those forms. Later as you shift to coding practices that are less barbaric you can verify nothing has regressed. There's no easy way to do this. Someone dug a deep hole for you to climb out of.

Comment: One thing I'd do is make a special comment near any of these things so you can quickly process all the source code using some analysis tool and pull out all the various conditions. Once you've extracted that data you can verify which of the combinations are actually used. (Who puts an `#ifdef` around an argument? I mean really!)

Comment: @tadman This is one of my favourite parts. In fact I am building up a little museum of such pieces of code. Maybe I publish it when it's over the top.

Comment: Sounds like a heck of a Medium or [Dev.to](http://dev.to) post in the making.

Comment: I'd try first to edit this code to exclude ifdefs around function parameters as much as possible. Maybe replace with default arguments, maybe exclude some paramers at all, if they never get compiled. Also you can try to combine this with std::optional, but this requires raising requirements to C++ compiler (must be C++17 or newer), not sure if you can do that. Or maybe pass parameters by pointer and make NULL default value. I know it is not the best idea in general, but lets you to simulate std::optional-like thing without C++17.

Comment: Generally, if it is not broken, you should not rewrite all code... Major refactoring is always a risk of breaking many things without realizing it. Maybe, original coder simply didn't knows much about virtual functions, templates and other things available in C++ and was just using C++ a a better C. Best is to first fix areas that are problemetic (known bugs) or where the risk is almost 0. Progressively, your code will get better.

Comment: @Phil1970 That's why the absolute very first thing you do is write tests on the existing behavior, as much as you can (yes the ifdefs complicate that). THEN refactor. Major refactoring with no test coverage at all is like walking a tightrope without a safety net.

Comment: What are the purpose of those 30 such processor directives? How many places a given define is checked? How much they are required (is the code in each branches almost duplicated)? Do you plan to keep those directives or remove them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to cover a C++ legacy code controlled by preprocessor #ifdefs with unittests?

Just write the unit tests for each needed tested case, compile each test case with different `#ifdefs` needed to test it, and run them.

> Did you ever encounter such a situation

I think I had a similar case. I was (trying to...) writing tests for software that used [GuruxDLMS.c library](https://github.com/Gurux/GuruxDLMS.c/blob/master/development/include/bytebuffer.h#L97) (and [here](https://github.com/Gurux/GuruxDLMS.c/blob/master/development/src/gxobjects.c#L665)).

> and how did you handle it?

Deciding how to compile stuff and running tests is a job for accommodating build system integrated around the project. Assuming for example CMake build system that I am comfortable with, I would just write the tests for each case and compile the library for each case:

```
function(add_cpp_legacy_code_library name)
     add_library(${name} sources.....cpp)
     target_compile_definitions(${name} PUBLIC ${ARGN})
endfunction()
function(add_cpp_legacy_code_test name sourcefile)
     add_cpp_legacy_code_library(${name}_library ${ARGN})
     add_executable(${name} ${sourcefile})
     target_link_libraries(${name} PRIVATE ${name}_library)
     add_test(NAME ${name} COMMAND ${name})
endfunction()

add_cpp_legacy_code_test(test1 some_test1.cpp
    PARAMETER=1
    SOME_PP_VAR1=4
    SOME_PP_VAR2=4
)
add_cpp_legacy_code_test(test2 some_test2.cpp
    PARAMETER=100
    SOME_PP_VAR1=1234
    SOME_PP_VAR2=7890
)
# etc...
```

Etc. for each macros combination that you want to test, where `some_test1.cpp` `some_test2.cpp` would either have `#if` for each macro combination or would be separate files.